# Is it possible to require a password to access a site hosted on firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting a site using firebase and want to be able to prevent people from accessing it, tried using a .htaccess file, wondering if anyone has been able to do it before.

Comment: This is not currently supported by Firebase Hosting.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Firebase Hosting is provided on top of a Node.js platform, so this should be possible in theory... (I haven't tested it): https://www.sitepoint.com/http-authentication-in-node-js/

Answer (score 23):

Here is a little hack that simulates HTTP Basic authentication using firebase cloud functions and a little rearrangement of files.

There are 3 steps to this:

1. Set up the necessary cloud function
2. Move the files you want to protect into a "secret" folder
3. Update your `firebase.json`

### 1. Cloud Function

```
const USERNAME = 'USERNAME'
const PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD' 
const denyAccess = (res) => {
  res.statusCode = 401;
  res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Authorization 
  Required');
  res.end('Unauthorized');
}

exports.authorizeAccess = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (typeof req.headers.authorization !== 'string') {
    denyAccess(res);
    return;
  }

  const base64Auth = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  if (typeof base64Auth !== 'string' ) {
   denyAccess(res);
   return;
  }

  const [user, pass] = Buffer.from(base64Auth, 
  'base64').toString().split(':');
  if (user !== USERNAME || pass !== PASSWORD) {
    denyAccess(res);
    return;
  }

  const urlObject = url.parse(req.url);
  urlObject.pathname = 
  `/${PASSWORD}${urlObject.pathname}`;
  const location = url.format(urlObject);

  res.writeHead(302, { location });
  res.end();
});
```

### 2. Move files into secret folder

Suppose the folder that you have set as `public` in `firebase.json` looks like this:

```
.
├── index.html
├── js
|   ├── main.js
|   └── main.js.map
└── styles.css
```

then make it look like this

```
.
└── PASSWORD
    ├── index.html
    ├── js
    |   ├── main.js
    |   └── main.js.map
    └── styles.css
```

### 3. `firebase.json`

```
{
  ...
  "rewrites": {
    "source": "/"
    "function": "authorizeAccess"
  }
  ...
}
```

We had to password protect our source maps in production; we had to have them in there in the first place so that Sentry would pick it up. Our build scripts would take care of moving the files into the necessary folder.

Comment: Great workaround. I guess this is the way until Google introduces an **dedicated** authentication and authorization system for it's static cloud hosting solution. Google actually acknowledges that it is a ["popular request"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296044/6086782). Let's see when they walk the talk. Thanks for sharing your solution, Rajiv Ram!  :D

Comment: To clarify, this will only require an auth at toplevel, the subfolder named _password_ is directly accessable if the url is known. I am unable to get the function running when visiting the subfolder.

Comment: What is `url` in the cloud function?

Comment: Got it, I believe it's as simple as importing one of the nodejs modules. `const url = require('url');`

Answer (score 6):

If you are hosting a site, and want to access firebase data on your site, you can add authentication to your application to control who can change or view data.  According to the manual:  [Firebase Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html)

Answer (score 0):

With [Firebase hosting channels](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-hosting-resources) you can have "preview" channels that include a random hash in their URLs, like `SITE_ID--CHANNEL_ID-RANDOM_HASH.web.app`. So that only people you gave this *secret* URL can access this site. Note that "preview" channels have an expiration delay that can be up to 30 days from the date of deploy.