# Enable Basic HTTP Authentication with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

We recently migrated from Divshot to Firebase and would like to protect the Website endpoint using Basic HTTP Authentication. Couldn't find this support in Firebase dashboard. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: We are not looking at Firebase for storing & retrieving data at this point, hence the authentication capabilities provided by Firebase for data access control doesn't help.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru this is a Firebase question, which is a server less solution. All Firebase Hosting questions have historically been handled on SO

Comment: @DavidEast: I'll retract my vote.

Comment: I think the question is around the Firebase dashboard having come from Divshot, after they have been acquired. Divshot use to have a nice feature where you could 'protect' an App through your App's dashboard limiting access to those with the username and password. It was a nice little feature, and handy when creating rapid prototypes. Anyhow since migrating to Firebase, I can not see this feature in the dashboard, maybe its possible using Node.js however it may require changing your App's architecture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to require a password to access a site hosted on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323630/is-it-possible-to-require-a-password-to-access-a-site-hosted-on-firebase)