# How to have basic authentication running on firebase web app?

Tags: firebase

I have hosted my app using firebase console hosting.

Now I want that this web app is only accessible by those user to whom I provide the stored username and password.

Meaning I require basic auth running on firebase app!

So what I require is shown in the screenshot. I achieve this thing via .net basic auth for azure.
https://iamlalit.tinytake.com/sf/MTIzMTQ4OF80NjgwMDk0

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to require a password to access a site hosted on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323630/is-it-possible-to-require-a-password-to-access-a-site-hosted-on-firebase)