# How to password protect a reactJS website that’s hosted in firebase with basic http authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, password-protection, firebase-hosting, basic-authentication

I couldn’t find an existing solution for password protecting a react website. I’m not referring to writing database rules, and protecting routes. I know few of those alternate solutions already. Also it’s not something like on a landing page too. But my problem is a password protection, which is prompted as soon as one tries to log-in to a website. It can be coming from a cloud just as an example.

It’s currently hosted in Firebase. I believe there should be something in GCloud if it’s hosted there, or any other cloud. I’ve already implemented it using the Authentication and Authorization in Firebase database. But it’s not protecting the entire site, and just the routes are protected. Also it’s slow.

Comment: You can use MD5 for this. While you insert and check is password is correct or not use MD5 library.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer Vivekanand. I’m new to web development. Could you please elaborate on that? Thank you.

Comment: Your issue is not clear enough.

Comment: Do NOT use MD5 as your password hash. It's incredibly insecure. What's the backend of your website built in? you can probably find online tutorials on authentication for your backend

Comment: It’s hosted in Firebase and also I’m using Firebase Firestore.

Comment: this may help you https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Comment: What exatly do you want to protect? It is not clear whether you need a user based login system for web pages, control access to web pages for a group of users with a shared password, or protect the database credentials your app needs to access the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to require a password to access a site hosted on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323630/is-it-possible-to-require-a-password-to-access-a-site-hosted-on-firebase)

Comment: @Perry - This is just Http basic authentication. Most web hosters offer to place a `.htpasswd` file in a given directory.

Comment: Thanks guys. Answers my question. (Y)

Comment: I switched to https://www.kintohub.com for that... they have a dynamic setup of basic auth there.